# Laravel Sanctum SPA authentication

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to setup a laravel api to work with a vue spa. API endpoints protected with `auth:sanctum` middleware only work when I add `web` middleware to them, which I don't think is right. Please help

Answer (score 1):

False alarm, I had forgotten to add
`\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,`
in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but from what I understand I should be able to use sessions on API endpoints is that correct?